# How do I deal with the results of a sqlite query in ruby?

Tags: ruby, types, sqlite

I have a simple task before me, query a database for the existence of a certain row via ruby's sqlite3 library. Below find my attempt.

There has got to be a better (less verbose) way than below. What is it? Is there something about Ruby's "Enumerable" class that I should be looking at? How do I determine the data type of sql results in general?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'sqlite3'

db = SQLite3::Database.open "example.db"

db.execute "create table if not exists example (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, words TEXT, whence DATETIME, number INT)"

words = "words"        

begin 
   insert = db.prepare "insert into example (words,whence,number) values (?,?,?)"
   insert.bind_param 1, words
   insert.bind_param 2, Time.now.to_s
   insert.bind_param 3, 42
   insert.execute
rescue SQLite3::Exception => e 
   puts "Problem with insert"
   puts e
end    

begin
    query = db.prepare "select count(*) as count from example where words = ?"
    query.bind_param 1, words
    rs = query.execute

    #puts rs.first
    res = rs.first.to_a

    puts res
    #if (rs.first.to_s.to_i > 0)
    if (res.first.to_i > 0)
        puts "rs.first greater than 0"
    else 
        puts "it won't get here."
    end 

    #if (rs.first == nil 
    #    puts "result is nil"
    #else 
    #    puts "result is NOT nil"
    #end

rescue SQLite3::Exception => e
    puts "Problem with query"
    puts e
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not actually have to count *all* matching rows, and neither is it necessary to look at the contents of the fetched row:

```
query = db.prepare "select 1 from example where words = ?"
query.bind_param 1, words
if query.execute.next
    puts "found."
else
    puts "it won't get here."
end
```

Comment: "It is not necessary to look at the contents of a fetched row" ... well and good, and your response underlines to me that the library returns a cursor, but my question was "How do I determine the data type of sql results in general?"

Comment: SQLite uses [dynamic typing](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), so you pretty much have to know what you will get. In general, generic database function should not need to call `to_*`.